# reading parameters on Sinatra post

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I'm working on my first Sinatra app and I have an hard time getting parameters from a post request.

I'm using MiniTest::Spec and my spec looks like

```
 payload = File.read("./spec/support/fixtures/payload.json")
 post "/api/v1/verify_payload", { payload: payload }, { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json" } 
 last_response.body.must_eql payload
```

And this is my route

```
namespace '/api/v1' do
  post '/verify_payload' do
    MultiJson.load(params[:payload])
  end
end
```

The spec fails because `last_response.body` is empty.

Am I missing something here?

I also tried to return the entire `params` from `verify_payload` but also in that case it returned an empty string.

**Update**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"payload":"xyz"}' http://localhost:9292/api/v1/verify_payload
```

does not return anything and no error on the server log

```
[2014-01-06 01:16:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=10449 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2014 01:16:27] "POST /api/v1/verify_payload HTTP/1.1" 200 6 0.0220
```

Thanks

Comment: The post is supposed to be invoked by a third-party service. I don't plan to invoke it from UI.

Comment: did you have a look into the logs?

Comment: Do you succeed with a GET request (or another route of course) ?  
btw: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/14293/ruby-sinatra-best-practices-for-project-structure read the comment dealing with Padrino.

Comment: Yes, GET requests work fine. ```curl http://localhost:9292/api/v1/whatever``` returns correctly
```from get request```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sinatra just doesn't parse this data, because they are not form parameters.

Form parameter would look like this

> curl -X POST 127.1:4567/ -d "foo=bar"

Instead of params you can just use `request.body.read` or use rack contrib.

**rack-contrib**

1. Install it with `gem install rack-contrib`
2. require it

> require 'rack'

> require 'rack/contrib'

3. load it `use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser`

with this you can use `params` as normal for json post data. Something like this:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"payload":"xyz"}' 127.1:4567/

source for this: [Sinatra controller params method coming in empty on JSON post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131763/), http://jaywiggins.com/2010/03/using-rack-middleware-to-parse-json/