# Sinatra + Redis and POST request with cURL

Tags: ruby, curl, redis, sinatra

I am learning Sinatra and Redis building a small URL Shortener. 
Here is my `POST` route:

```
helpers do
 include Rack::Utils
 alias_method :h, :escape_html

 def random_string(length)
  rand(36**length).to_s(36)
 end
end

post '/' do
 if params[:url].present?
 content_type :json
 @shortcode = random_string 5
 short_url = redis.setnx "links:#{@shortcode}", params[:url]
 short_url.to_json
 end
end
```

This POST method will take a long URL as input and generate a short one as output in jSON format.

But, when I try to do this with cURL using

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"url": "http://mywebsite.com"}' http://localhost:4567
```

it fails and I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `present?' for nil:NilClass.
```

Any hint?

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading parameters on Sinatra post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932779/reading-parameters-on-sinatra-post)